# Checking if ModelBuilder model is in use by testing for Schema locks?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, arcgis-10.3, lock

Is it possible to get ArcGIS to check if someone else is using a model by checking schema lock and potentially display an error saying that it is already in use and maybe provide information on who it is thats using it?

Answer (score 2):

[Another GIS Blog](http://anothergisblog.blogspot.com.au/2011/07/testing-for-schema-locks.html) informs us that an ArcPy function:

> [TestingSchemaLock](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018v0000002m000000) tests if a feature class or table has a schema lock.

That posting contains ArcPy code that you could use to develop a Python Script Tool that you could include in your model to check whether the data that your model uses has a schema lock, but not necessarily whether your model is being used.